# Passport lost, new passport issued, then old passport found

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, passports, lost-documents, kuwait

I have lost my passport as 11/07/2019 in Bus (travel from Gorakhpur to Lucknow). After that i did FIR and i applied for re-issue passport. 
But unfortunately i have received my passport which i lost as on 27/07/2019 by courier. Some one send the passport. Now i have both passport my old passport and new passport which i reissued. But visa is printed in old passport valied til 01/01/2020. Now i have to travel to Kuwait. Can i travel on same visa. And can carry both passport for safety purposes. 
Kindly guide me

Comment: Call the passport office and check if you have to report that. Usually, when we renew the passport, they will cancel the old passport and give it back. I suspect a similar canceled seal is needed in the passport.

Comment: The old passport may be in various databases of lost and possibly stolen passports, so check with the passport office before using it even for the visa.

Comment: Also check with the Kuwaiti Ministry of Interior regarding the continuing validity of your visa and whether you can apply for it to be transferred to your new passport or whether you require a new visa https://eservices1.moi.gov.kw/moicus.nsf/EngContactUs?OpenForm